# What do you call a person who fights injustice?

Tags: meaning

I need to know what a person is called who hates injustice in the world and fights for equality for all.

Comment: A good person..

Comment: [Captain America](http://injusticefanon.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_(Avengeance))?

Comment: Maybe more to the point, please do name just one person that does not hate injustice.

Answer (score 2):

**egalitarian**

> someone who believes that all people deserve equal rights, equal opportunities, equal treatment, or any sort of equality.

You can read more on egalitarianism through https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egalitarianism/

Answer (score 2):

In recent years people who fight against injustice and for equality have been called *social justice warriors*. The Wikipedia article on this term documents the change in the term's connotation since it was first coined a decade or so ago:

> The phrase originated in the late 20th century as a neutral or
>   positive term for people engaged in social justice activism. In
>   2011, when the term first appeared on Twitter, it changed from a
>   primarily positive term to an overwhelmingly negative one. During
>   the Gamergate controversy, the negative connotation gained increased
>   use, and was particularly aimed at those espousing views adhering to
>   social liberalism, cultural inclusivity, or feminism, as well as views
>   deemed to be politically correct.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_justice_warrior

*Urban Dictionary*'s typically abrasive definition of *social justice warrior* is:

> A person who uses the fight for civil rights as an excuse to be rude,
>   condescending, and sometimes violent for the purpose of relieving
>   their frustrations or validating their sense of unwarranted moral
>   superiority. The behaviors of Social justice warriors usually have a
>   negative impact on the civil rights movement, turning away potential
>   allies and fueling the resurgence of bigoted groups that scoop up
>   people who have been burned or turned off by social justice warriors.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Social%20Justice%20Warrior

There is a discussion of the etymology of the term here on this site at:

[Origin of the phrase "social justice warrior"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202080/origin-of-the-phrase-social-justice-warrior)

Comment: Agreed, +1. But note that this is only a subset of the people who fight injustice. For example, Mari-Lou's "Captain America" or the Avengers, all chartered to fight injustice, would not be described as SJWs.

Answer (score -1):

Egalitarian :

believing in or based on the principle that all people are equal and deserve equal rights and opportunities,a person who advocates or supports the principle of equality for all people.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egalitarianism

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egalitarianism/

Comment: This was suggested in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/472449/55623) posted yesterday. Your answer contains the same quote and identical link. Please review existing answers before posting your own.